# Minecraft scoreboard command to kill an item with a certain name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have commands set up to kill an item whenever they touch the ground. In this case it is iron boots but I want to know how I can kill iron boots with a certain name. I think I have to add the custom name into the following command:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] IronB 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:iron_boots}}
```

But I don't know how to add the custom name. I couldn't find a solution anywhere, and tried to figure it out myself but failed. Sorry if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Does the item entity have the name (like how you name things with nametags) or the item inside the entity have the name (like how you name things with anvils)?

Comment: I name it with the /give command, if that is what you're asking

Comment: So you're doing something like `display:{Name:"named item"}` and not `CustomName:"named item"`, correct? Just making sure because a dropped item has two different types of name.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but someone already got it, i appreciate  you taking the time to try to help me :)

Comment: "someone already got it" - that person was me :P, I took a guess that you probably meant the former.

Comment: Lol! I didn't bother looking at the names xD was in a rush, Thanks tho *thumbs up*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want should be:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] IronB 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:iron_boots,tag:{display:{Name:"Named boots"}}}}
```

Where you replace `Named boots` with the item name you have given them.

Then `/kill @e[score_IronB_min=1]`.

Comment: Thank you, When i was trying to figure out how to do it by myself i did the command the way how you presented it, but i added 2 brackets to finish the command not 4 lol

Comment: If colorfusion's answer was helpful, please upvote it (if you haven't already) to show your appreciation.